# C++; eclipse linker error

Tags: c++, arduino, avr-gcc, winavr

So working on getting my eclipse IDE going so I can develop my arduino uno in eclipse. 
My C++ is weak so this is probably a nube error on my part.

I have a blink program that looks for an arduino library I compiled from the arduino IDE's library.
My code points to the header file and my code find it fine; meaning I can click on:

```
#include <arduino.h>
```

and go view the header

this: "C:/programs/arduino-1.0/hardware/arduino/cores/328p_lib/libuno_library.a"
is a valid path... but I get the following error:

```
>****** Build of configuration Debug for project project1 ****
>make all 
>Building target: project1.elf
>Invoking: AVR C++ Linker
>avr-g++ -Wl,-Map,project1.map,--cref -L"C:\programs\arduino->1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\328p_lib" -mmcu=atmega328p -o "project1.elf"  ./code/code1.o   >-l"C:/programs/arduino-1.0/hardware/arduino/cores/328p_lib/libuno_library.a"
>c:/programs/winavr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.3/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ->lC:/programs/arduino-1.0/hardware/arduino/cores/328p_lib/libuno_library.a
>make: *** [project1.elf] Error 1
>**** Build Finished ******
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after wasting 2 days or so of fun time I finally found the problem.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-eclipse/forums/forum/664382/topic/4640554

When adding the static library to the linker you have to remove the lib prefix and the .a suffix. not sure what that is about.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project>Click on C/C++ BUild> Settings > GCC C++ Linker> Libraries

Click the first icon Add> Add the library name ( without the .a suffix, the suffix will be added automatically)

This will ensure that the library is added to the project.

If the library is part of another project >Go to GCC C Compiler> directories >Add the directory

This will ensure that the library is there for getting the compilation done.

Comment: Project> build > settings ->AVR c++ Compiler->Directories has:
"C:\programs\arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\328-import"
&
"C:\programs\arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\328p_lib"

Also added to c/c++ General-> GNU c++-> Includes and Libraries  contains an entry for the libuno_library.a

 No change in error.

Comment: I should have been more specific..Yes, you are not supposed to add the .a suffix because the suffix is updated automatically. Glad you were able to resolve this.